# Codeigniter/ PHP MySQL Join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables: 'competitions' and 'entries'. On my competition table, I have a "completed" column that tells me if the competition has been run. On my entries table I have a user ID column and a competitions ID column. I am trying to create a JOIN in which I see if the user is able to compete by checking all the rows in the 'entries' table and then for each particular row checking if the corresponding competition ID is completed in the 'competitions' table. I'm not very strong with my joins and so far am slightly lost. This is what I have so far but it's not working properly:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('entries');
$this->db->join('competitions', 'competitions.id = entries.competition_id');
$this->db->where('entries.user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('competitions.complete', '0'); //0 for incomplete, 1 for complete
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return FALSE; //user is currently in an active competition
}else {
    return TRUE; //user is not in an active competition
}
```

I am currently working in Codeigniter but an explanation in regular PHP would be fine also. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: `$this->db->join('competitions', 'competitions.id = entries.competition_id','left');`

Comment: What is the output of the query? Are there any rows? Can you output the actual query text being sent to MySQL?

Comment: Got it working. It seemed to be an issue between my controller and model. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may use left or right joins for better result you wish to get...

```
$this->db->join('table2','table1.id = table2.id','LEFT/RIGHT');
```

I thnk you can also use inner,outer joins...May hope it is useful